# How to "unconcatenate" a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have the following pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

print(df)

     time      Group      blocks
0     1        A           4
1     2        A           7
2     3        A           12
3     4        A           17
4     5        A           21 
5     6        A           26
6     7        A           33
7     8        A           39
8     9        A           48
9     10       A           59
    ....        ....          ....
36     35      A           231
37     1       B           1
38     2       B           1.5
39     3       B           3
40     4       B           5
41     5       B           6
    ....        ....          ....
911    35      Z           349
```

This is a dataframe with multiple time series-esque data, from `min=1` to `max=35`. Each `Group` has a relationship in the range `time=1` to `time=35` .

I would like to segment this dataframe into columns Group A, Group B, Group C, etc.

How does one "unconcatenate" this dataframe?

Comment: So want to have 26 columns at the end?

Comment: @JoeR Yes, that's correct

Comment: So then, @MaxU 's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [84]: df.pivot_table(index='time', columns='Group')
Out[84]:
      blocks
Group      A    B
time
1        4.0  1.0
2        7.0  1.5
3       12.0  3.0
4       17.0  5.0
5       21.0  6.0
6       26.0  NaN
7       33.0  NaN
8       39.0  NaN
9       48.0  NaN
10      59.0  NaN
35     231.0  NaN
```

data:

```
In [86]: df
Out[86]:
    time Group  blocks
0      1     A     4.0
1      2     A     7.0
2      3     A    12.0
3      4     A    17.0
4      5     A    21.0
5      6     A    26.0
6      7     A    33.0
7      8     A    39.0
8      9     A    48.0
9     10     A    59.0
36    35     A   231.0
37     1     B     1.0
38     2     B     1.5
39     3     B     3.0
40     4     B     5.0
41     5     B     6.0
```